# Looping through values of a variable using randomForest in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach

I've been trying to run a randomForest model for different values. I'm  used to using the "foreach" command in STATA - but it seems R works different.

I've searched for quite some time with no success, for something that is quite simple (I think). Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm running the following randomForest model:

```
modelRandom = randomForest(y~a+b+c+d+e, data=dataframe, mtry=4, ntree=30)
```

Now - after this I want to predict probabilities for each observation like so:

```
Prob<-predict(modelRandom, dataframe, type = 'prob')
```

Now comes the issue: I want to loop through the values of one the variables (b) in the randomForest model and predict probabilities for each value.

This (b) variable contains twelve different values (1:12). I want R to change the b variable of each observation into 1 and predict probability, then change the b variable of all observations in 2 predict probability again. Then to 3, 4, 5 and so on.

It should then put all these probabilities into one table, with the corresponding variable c next to it, like so:

```
C prob1 prob2 prob3 prob4 prob5 prob6 prob7 prob8 prob9 prob10 prob11 prob12
```

I want the C in there otherwise I can't tell which observation the probabilities belong to.

I've come up with this, but I think I'm not remotely close to what I want:

```
for(b in dataframe){
prob[b]<-predict(modelRandom, dataframe, type = 'prob')
}
```

As asked here's some more information about the dataset. I've masked some of it because it contains client information which I can't share obviously.

```
structure(list(X = c("NVT", "NVT", "NVT", "NVT", "NVT", 
"NVT"), a = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), d= structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Dhr.", 
"Mevr."), class = "factor"), c = c("3331GE", "2285EH", 
"9401GE", "5591DZ", "2611CE", "1359KB"), b = structure(c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), e = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8"), class = "factor"), .Names = c("X", "a", "d", "c", "b", "e"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide example data. Use `dput(head(dataframe))` and copy the output from the console into your question.

Comment: Added them for you.

Comment: I assume you want the probabilities of `X` taking on the value `"1"` in your table?

Comment: If we're referring to the X which contains "NVT" then no. X shouldn't be in the table. The final table should contain the (12) probabilities for each observation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a bit of a larger data pool since the one you provided can not be used to build a model:

First simulate some data:

```
r_data <- data.frame(y = as.factor(sample(0:1, 100, replace =T)), 
                     matrix(rnorm(1000), 100),
                     b = sample(1:12, 100, replace = T))
```

extract row names:

```
names_rows <- rownames(r_data)
```

Here we have `y` as a binary outcome,
10 numeric features X1 - X10,
and b with values 1 to 12

Make the model:

```
library(randomForest)
modelRandom <- randomForest(y~., data = r_data, mtry = 4, ntree = 30)
```

Make the new data for predictions, by replicating the numeric features 12 times and adding all values of b - `1:12`

```
n_row <- nrow(r_data)

newdata <- data.frame(r_data[rep(1:n_row, 12), 2:11], b = rep(1:12, each =  n_row))
```

Get predictions on the new data and cbind the b column from above

```
preds <- data.frame(predict(modelRandom, newdata, type = 'prob'),
                    b = rep(1:12, each = n_row),
                    names_rows = as.numeric(rep(names_rows, times = 12)))
```

Clean into desired output:

```
library(tidyverse)

preds %>%
  select(X1, b, names_rows) %>% #select only prob for outcome 1 and the b column
  group_by(b)  %>%
  mutate(z = 1 :  n_row) %>% #generate unique row identifier 
  spread(b, X1) %>% #convert to wide format
  select(-z) #remove unique row identifier 
    #output:

# A tibble: 100 x 13
   names_rows        `1`        `2`        `3`        `4`       `5`        `6`
 *      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1          1 0.30000000 0.30000000 0.30000000 0.30000000 0.3000000 0.30000000
 2          2 0.70000000 0.70000000 0.73333333 0.73333333 0.7000000 0.70000000
 3          3 0.23333333 0.23333333 0.23333333 0.23333333 0.2000000 0.20000000
 4          4 0.33333333 0.30000000 0.26666667 0.26666667 0.3000000 0.26666667
 5          5 0.30000000 0.30000000 0.33333333 0.30000000 0.3000000 0.26666667
 6          6 0.23333333 0.20000000 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.2000000 0.16666667
 7          7 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.1000000 0.06666667
 8          8 0.26666667 0.23333333 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.1666667 0.16666667
 9          9 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.16666667 0.10000000 0.1000000 0.10000000
10         10 0.83333333 0.83333333 0.90000000 0.83333333 0.8333333 0.86666667
# ... with 90 more rows, and 6 more variables: `7` <dbl>, `8` <dbl>, `9` <dbl>,
#   `10` <dbl>, `11` <dbl>, `12` <dbl>
```

to save it in an object:

```
preds %>%
  select(X1, b, names_rows) %>% column
  group_by(b)  %>%
  mutate(z = 1 :  n_row) %>%
  spread(b, X1) %>% 
  select(-z) -> saved_object
```

Comment: Up until the last part it goes well. The cleaning isn't going well. First problem is I get : 

Error in preds %>% select(X1, ti) %>% group_by(ti) %>% mutate(z = 1:n_row) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

I removed the %>% and ran it, it worked. But the output is directly in my console. Isn't there a way to put it in data table which I can export?

Lastly there is no unique identifier for each observation which is connected to the initial "dataframe" data. I want a row identifier which is also in the dataframe data.

Comment: @Olli Sagi  The function  `%>%` comes from `library(tidyverse)`. Install it and load it. It has a powerful set of functions for all sorts of data wrangling. The data is arranged the same way it is in the initial data.frame. I will provide additional code in the edit.

Comment: Okay, so now I think I've got it almost all figured out. The only problem I'm having is that the "b" you are using in the example is a seperate dataset. Whilst in my environment it is inside the r_data/newdata as a column. So when I try to run the last part it says: Error in group_by(b) Object "b" not found.

Comment: @Olli Sagi please check the line `preds <- data.frame....` `b` is defined as a column there.

Comment: I'm still having an issue, here check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512830/same-probability-for-every-hour-in-a-loop-with-randomforest